# Google chrome html5 support

Tags: html, google-chrome

Is there any ready OFFICIAL reference for html5 support for google chrome? I see chrome and chromium blogs has lot of information, but looking for a table or a simple page where one can see the developments on html5 support. For example I want to see when the html5 datepicker would be supported? (as i read online, only Opera supports it Now( the articles are one year old:-) )

thanks.

Comment: Both Chrome 12 and Safari 5 offer some support for the datepicker (as of July 2011), but they don't offer a popup to select a date.  It's rather lame.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Check out [When Can I Use...](http://caniuse.com/#search=date%20picker) Really helpful!**

To answer your question: It's only fully supported in Opera and Chrome. Full support by all browsers isn't to be expected in the near future.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I don't know about any official references, but I can at least talk of my experience:

At the moment my google chrome 8.0 scores 231 of 300 points in the http://html5test.com/.

Parsing Rules, Canvas, Audio, Geolocation, Communication (Sockets and the like), Files and Workers have 100% points, so they are fully implemented.

Video, Elements, Forms, User Interaction, Application Cache and Storage are mostly supported. But your example, the datepicker, is not supported. It is just rendered as an input field with two arrows (up and down), with which you can cycle your date up or down.

Local Devices (device element), Microdata and WebGL are not yet supported.

But the Chromium 10.0 I have at home supports WebGL.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't an official one I don't believe but this is by far the best I've ever seen:

http://fmbip.com/litmus

Answer (score 2):

Here's another resource. It's not official but quite informative http://html5test.com

Answer (score 0):

There is a most recent update with is http://html6test.com/ this is pretty much like Html 5.1 version